# Error on TFS Build Server when deploying app to web server

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am getting this error on my build server when the build definition runs that deploys the app to the web server. This assembly is in the GAC on the build server.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4377): Web deployment task failed. (The assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.batchparser, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' could not be loaded.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND.)
```